# How to use sprockets 4 with Rails 5 after upgrade

Tags: sprockets, ruby-on-rails-5

I've being trying to use Rails 5 after upgrade my Rails 4.2 app.

After change the version I used the command `bundle exec rake rails:update`

I got the error when I access some view:

```
Asset `application.css` was not declared to be precompiled in  production.
Declare links to your assets in `assets/config/manifest.js`.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since sprockets 4 requires the `manifest.js` file you have to create the file `assets/config/manifest.js`, it was suppose to be created on the generator, but since it was not defined where to put the file, it does not create for now. **The location(or type, from js to yml) of the file it might change until Rails 5 release, so be aware.**

Add some options like below, [suggested by @Eileen from Basecamp](http://eileencodes.com/posts/the-sprockets-4-manifest/):

```
// JS and CSS bundles
//
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css


// Images and fonts so that views can link to them
//
//= link_tree ../fonts
//= link_tree ../images
```